# Is returning a cursor to fewer columns of a database more efficient

Tags: android, database, list, cursor, android-listview

I have looked for a similar question and haven't been able to find one.

I generally use a separate database class in which i define functions to return cursors.
For example,

```
public Cursor all(Activity activity) //cursor for Activities
{
    String[] from = { _ID, column1, column2, column3, column4};

    String order = _ID;

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, from, null, null, null, null, order);
    activity.startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
}
```

Then from the activity i can use-
`Cursor cursor = database.all(Activity.this);` to get an instance of the cursor.

My question is this, suppose i do not need all the column values but say only the first three, is it worth it in terms of performance to define another function in the database class that returns only the first three column values with the cursor.(especially if i am using the cursor to populate a list)

Just so you know, I came across this question while implementing a custom list adapter where i do not need all the column values to draw the list items.

Comment: Is it ultimately better to use a single cursor connection where i am reading all the columns or use separate cursor connections.

Comment: Why don't you just allow the caller to pass the projection (in your case named `from`) parameter to your `all` function?

Comment: yes it will effect performance, as mobile devices have limited processing power+memory
And idea of Jens will do the job

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the answer, what you suggest is a great way to implement the cursor.

Comment: @pst While you're right that it should be inconsequential, I think i am going to use Jens answer in the future. (all about it being the right way etc.)